# ECS getting notification when service update completes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When updating ECS service, new docker container is deployed one by one until every container is replaced by new version.

We'd like to know when new version is fully deployed, I guess it could mean either of these

- all old version task has been deregistered, and at least one new version task has registered
- every old version task has been replaced by newer version

Can we get a notification for either of the two events ?

(possible via stack)

Answer (score 2):

Both events seem related [Task State Change Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_task_events),as both related to task level event.

> all old version task has been deregistered, and at least one new
>   version task has registered

seems like you need  State changes from **RUNNING to STOPPED**, as a result of deregistration process, container **STOPPED or Terminated.**

For this purpose you can create cloud watch rule, it will fire whenever STOPPED event occurs.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "clusterArn": [
      "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789:cluster/cluster-a",
      "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:123456789:cluster/cluster-b"
       ]
  }
}
```

Set the target SNS or lambda to receive event, this will trigger a notification whenever task stats changes in the above two cluster.

> every old version task has been replaced by a newer version

This event is more related to service level event, AWS recently announce this feature, as you are intrested at profer deployment event, while service only fire `SERVICE_STEADY_STATE` when the task is up and running in the service.

> Previously, customers could receive CloudWatch Events for ECS Tasks
>   and Instances, but ECS Service events were only available through ECS
>   APIs, requiring customers to poll an API and implement their own logic
>   for automation and logging of Service events. With ECS Service Action
>   events in CloudWatch Events, customers can easily automate real-time
>   responses to events as they occur. For example, customers can
>   automatically trigger an AWS Lambda function in response to specific
>   ECS Service Actions. Or, customers can stream all ECS Service Action
>   events to a CloudWatch Logs group, enabling post-event forensic
>   analysis.

[amazon-ecs-service-events-now-available-as-cloudwatch-events-2019-11](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-ecs-service-events-now-available-as-cloudwatch-events/)

**SERVICE_STEADY_STATE**

The service is healthy and at the desired number of tasks, thus reaching a steady state.

You can try something like

```
{
    "source": [
        "aws.ecs"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "ECS Service Action"
    ],
  "detail": {
    "eventName": [
      "SERVICE_STEADY_STATE"
    ]
}
```

[ecs_service_events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_service_events)